# CS50 Problem Set 9, Impossible problem in the terminal

Tags: python, html, css, flask, cs50

CS50 Problem set 9,
I keep getting this error:

`:( buy handles valid purchase expected to find "112.00" in page, but it wasn't found`

This is the buy route:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    if request.method == "POST":
        stock_symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        if not stock_symbol:
            return apology("must provide stock symbol", 400)

        stock_info = lookup(stock_symbol)
        if not stock_info:
            return apology("must provide valid stock symbol", 400)


        # Validate shares input
        shares_input = request.form.get("shares")
        if not shares_input or not shares_input.isdigit():
            return apology("must provide a valid number of shares", 400)

        shares = int(shares_input)

        if shares < 1 or shares % 1 != 0:
            return apology("invalid number of shares", 400)


        try:
            #retrieving price
            stock_price = stock_info["price"]

            #retrieving purchase date
            purchase_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


            #verifying enough funds and setting new cash
            cash_owned = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])[0]["cash"]
            cash_spent = stock_price * shares
            cash_updated = cash_owned - cash_spent

            if cash_updated < 0:
                return apology("Insufficient funds", 400)

            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", cash_updated, session["user_id"])


            #inserting new informations
            #check if users already had shares
            existing_shares = db.execute("SELECT number FROM purchase_history WHERE symbol = ? AND id = ?", stock_symbol, session["user_id"])

            user_info = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
            username = user_info[0]["username"]


            if existing_shares:
                shares_owned = existing_shares[0]["number"]
                shares_updated = shares_owned + shares
                db.execute("INSERT INTO purchase_history (username, symbol, number, purchase_price, purchase_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                                username, stock_symbol, shares_updated, stock_price, purchase_date)

            else:
                db.execute("INSERT INTO purchase_history (username, symbol, number, purchase_price, purchase_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                                username, stock_symbol, shares, stock_price, purchase_date)


            flash(f"Bought {shares} share of {stock_symbol.upper()} for {cash_spent}, Updated cash: {cash_updated}")

            return redirect("/")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception during purchase: {e}")
            flash("An error occurred during the purchase")
            return redirect("/")


    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

this is the index route:

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    cash_balance = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])[0]["cash"]


    user_info = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
    username = user_info[0]["username"]


    # Retrieve user's stock portfolio
    portfolio = db.execute(
        "SELECT symbol, SUM(number) as total_shares, MAX(purchase_price) as purchase_price, MAX(purchase_date) as purchase_date FROM purchase_history WHERE username = ? GROUP BY symbol",
        username
    )

    # Calculate the total value of each stock and the overall portfolio
    total_value = 0

    for stock in portfolio:
        stock_symbol = stock["symbol"]
        total_shares = stock["total_shares"]
        purchase_price = stock["purchase_price"]
        purchase_date = stock["purchase_date"]

        stock_info = lookup(stock_symbol)
        current_price = stock_info["price"]
        stock_value = total_shares * current_price
        total_value += stock_value

        stock.update({
            "current_price": current_price,
            "stock_value": stock_value,
            "positive_change": stock_value >= 0,
            "value": current_price * total_shares
        })

    overall_value = cash_balance + total_value

    return render_template("index.html", portfolio=portfolio, cash_balance=cash_balance, overall_value=overall_value)
```

this is buy.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Buy
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h2>Buy stocks</h2>
    <form action="/buy" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="symbol" placeholder="Stock Symbol" autofocus autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="shares" placeholder="Number of Shares" autocomplete="off">

        <button type="submit">Buy</button>
    </form><br>
    <br>


{% endblock %}
```

And this is index.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Home
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>Portfolio Overview</h1>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Shares</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>TOTAL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for stock in portfolio %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ stock["symbol"].upper() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock["total_shares"] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock["current_price"] | usd }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock["value"] | usd }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <h3>Cash: {{ cash_balance | usd }}</h3>
    <h3>TOTAL: {{ overall_value | usd }}</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

these are the sql tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, hash TEXT NOT NULL, cash NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 10000.00);
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username ON users (username);
CREATE TABLE purchase_history (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        username TEXT NOT NULL,
        symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
        number INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        purchase_price REAL,
        purchase_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        CONSTRAINT unique_purchase UNIQUE (username, symbol, purchase_date));
```